# How to handle nulls in linq to entities

Tags: linq-to-entities

How do you handle a null for a Max value in a linq to entities statement?

```
int UserLevelID = db.Characters.Where(o => o.UserId == UserID).Max(o => o.LevelID);
```

Comment: Yeap. Sorry. I am just getting the MAx ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say count, since you aren't referring to count anywhere in that code.  If you are wonding how to handle a null `o.LevelID` you could do something like this:

```
Max(o => o.LevelID ?? -1);
```

`??` is the coalesce operator in .NET

UPDATE

Try this:

```
db.Characters.Where(o => o.UserId == UserID).Max(o => o == null ? 0 : o.LevelID);
```

Comment: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'

Comment: I am trying to find if the user has another row (record). If he does then I want the max value of that row for LevelID. If the user does not have a single row I get an exception

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following, replacing 'IFNULLDEFAULTVALUE' with what you want the value to be if o.LevelID is null:

```
int UserLevelID = db.Characters.Where(o => o.UserId == UserID).Max(o => (o.LevelID != null ? o.LevelID : IFNULLDEFAULTVALUE);
```